# Filling color misalignment in merged cells with tabularray in LaTeX

Tags: tabularray

The background color of a merged cell is misaligned when there is a page break with the `tabularray` package in LaTeX

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,tabularx,xcolor}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\definecolor{tablebackground}{RGB}{245,246,246}
\SetTblrInner[longtblr]{cells={bg=tablebackground}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c]},rowhead=1}
head1&head2\\
\SetCell[r=35]{m}1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\1&2\\


\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain the `\SetCell[r=35]{m}`? It seems to be the cause. You really want a cell to be 35-row high?

Comment: @Miyase This one is just a case. In fact, I have similar needs, otherwise, I would not find this problem.

Comment: OK, just wanted to be sure. I tried with `tabularray`'s new syntax and the result is the same. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: @Miyase What? What's the new syntax? May you send me the link which shows the new syntax？

Comment: It's in the first pages of the manual, pages 17-18 for multirow / multicol. Basically, any time you're putting formatting commands inside the table, it's the old syntax. But the engine behind is likely identical, so it won't solve your problem.

Comment: @Miyase Okay. I should use `multi` not `SetCell`, am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. In your case, it would be `cell{2}{1}={r=35}{m}` in the `tblr` environment's arguments.

Comment: @Miyase It's difficult to understand, I can't imagine it but doesn't affect the question.

Comment: It means: the cell located row 2 column 1 must be 35-row high and vertically centered (m).

Comment: @Miyase Yes! But the background of merged cell was put on the page before not on the page it should have been.